# iTunes Allow App Update

Tags: iphone, ios, version, itunes

I've just released a new version of our App.  It:

- is live and shows in the App Store
- shows in "Updates" on the device
- successfully updates via the device

However, in iTunes, it says the new version is already downloaded and hence doesn't appear in the list of updates and cannot be updated.

If do a sync after the update on the device, the device copy reverts to the old version.

I cannot see what I'm doing wrong.  Is there a bug in iTunes? I've googled but only found reference to a bug where it keeps saying there's an update, even when you've updated it.  That seems to be the opposite problem to the one I have.

I'd really appreciate any pointers you may have so I know where to look.

Many thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have just found what I'm doing wrong.

I have two accounts, one personal, one as a developer.  I downloaded it originally on the developer account but just now I was signed in on my personal account.

As soon as I signed in on the developer account, there it was.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked all the references to the Version metadata in your SDK? It might be that you have forgotten to update a version number somewhere and by coincidence it is the one iTunes uses.